# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in REST API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, maven

So I am quite new to REST API development and for my app, I used spring boot initializer. I was getting an error with hibernate being unable to access my oracle database and I later found that I had mistakenly added a derby dependency which was somehow clashing with the DB access. After I took it out and what is related to it I got this error. Am I missing something important here?

Also, I'd like to apologize for how long this is but I'm truly desperate

Here is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartScopeInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:445)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:427)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:420)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:272)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.example.TNDservice.TnDserviceApplication.main(TnDserviceApplication.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:441)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TNDservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TNDservice</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.library>2.9.8</jackson.library>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--        Springboot dependancies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--Oracle sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--jackson-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--lambok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!--junit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>icm</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>RESTservice</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>


</project>
```

this is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "con.example.TNDservice")
public class TnDserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TnDserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spring-boot version is 2.2.5 but spring framework version is 4.3.0, I think by default spring framework version is 5.x.x for this spring-boot version, you could try updating spring framework version for the spring-boot or use https://start.spring.io/ to generate the pom with required versions. This might also help [unresolvable dependency org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector.isKotlinReflectPresent()z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734495/unresolvable-dependency-org-springframework-core-kotlindetector-iskotlinreflectp)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manually override the dependency versions without *very good* reason.

The ones predefined with Spring Boot are verified to work well together, but you are downgrading a couple of versions severely.

So, you might want to delete these lines:

```
    <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.library>2.9.8</jackson.library>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
```